# Retrieve rows between the date range based on total days

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I've a IQueryable result queried from the db using LINQ, now I had to filter all the rows based on a field date_sent. No. of days should be calculated from date_sent to current date. this total no. of days that falls undet 0 to 30 days range should be retrieved. How do I do it. I have the below code but it's not working. no errors but does not filter properly.

```
query = query.Where(x => x.DATE_SENT != null);

query = query.Where(x => (int)(EntityFunctions.DiffDays(currentDate, (DateTime)x.DATE_SENT)) >= 0 && 
                         (int)(EntityFunctions.DiffDays(currentDate, (DateTime)x.DATE_SENT)) <= 30);
```

Any guidance on how it can be handled will be great.

Comment: How does It not filter properly. What do you get. What do you expect instead?

Comment: I'm expecting 6 rows, but only one row gets returned. I've verified for the date_sent to fall between 0-30days, but dosen't show up.

Comment: You need get rows from last 30 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it using this query.

```
var dtDiff = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30);
query  = query.Where(z=>  z.DATE_SENT >= dtDiff);
```

31-60 days

```
   var dtDiff31 =DateTime.Now.AddDays(-31);
   var dtDiff60 =DateTime.Now.AddDays(-60);
   query  = query.Where(z=>  z.DATE_SENT >= dtDiff60 && z.DATE_SENT <= dtDiff31 );
```

Comment: I tried your code. It threw me error "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddDays(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression"

Comment: Thanks that works for 0-30days, I need the next range 31-60days. How do you set the range?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just want to filter by a range of dates:

```
DateTime filterDate = currentDate.AddDays(-30);

query = query.Where(x => x.DATE_SENT >= filterDate);
```

In case your `currentDate` can vary you add the second condition:

```
query = query.Where(x => x.DATE_SENT >= filterDate && x.DATE_SENT < currentDate);
```